# Python and selenium invalid syntax

Tags: python, selenium

When I enter this it says `invalid syntax` at the `end.click`. and `webdriverwait wait`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time 
import random as r
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
nt = "Enter Name: "
np = "Enter Password: "
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.delugerpg.com/login")
time.sleep(1)
login = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
login.send_keys(nt)
login = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
login.send_keys(np)
login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1)

driver.get("https://www.delugerpg.com/battle/gym/108")
found = True
while found == True:
        link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-battle-action")
        link.click()
        print("Starting Battle")
        time.sleep(1)
        attack1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-battle-action")
        attack1.click()
        print("Take this")
        time.sleep(1)
        link1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-battle-action")
        link1.click
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,1)
        end = wait.until(EC.presence_of_elements_located(("Class","btn.battle-default"))
        end.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Your indentation is wrong

2.You are missing a space between `new` and `WebDriverWait`

3.You have a semi-colon `;` on the `WebDriverWait` line when you shouldn't

4.You have have 2 backticks ``` `` ``` at the end of the `attack1` line

5.`WebDriverWaitwait` should be `WebDriverWait wait` and you are missing a parenthesis

6.If you define the variable `wait` you need to use it on the actual `wait` call beneath it, not call `WebDriverWait` again

7.Your `presence_Of_Elements_Located` should be `presence_of_elements_located` if more than one or `presence_of_element_located` if single element

```
while found == True:
        link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-battle-action")
        link.click()
        print("Starting Battle")
        time.sleep(1)
        attack1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-battle-action")
        attack1.click()
        print("Take this")
        time.sleep(1)
        link1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-battle-action")
        link1.click()
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,1)
        end = wait.until(EC.presence_of_elements_located(("Class","btn.battle-default")))
        end.click()
```

If that doesn't solve it we will need to see more of your code

Comment: This still wont fix it. Syntax error will appear again.

Comment: Then we will need to see more code like I said

Comment: No, we have one minor problem. Check the second to last line. Look at the parentheses. XD

Comment: Good catch.  Updated answer

Comment: Thanks sorry im so bad at programing this is the first time I've wrote anything and i updated my question and put the whole script up. @JD2775

Comment: Check #5 on my list.  You are missing a right parenthesis at the end of the 2nd to last line. I just realized I called it out but didn't actually change the code on my end before.  Fixed now

Comment: You were also missing the `()` after `link1.click`

Comment: Thank you soo much (:

Comment: no problem :)  Please accept/upvote the answer if it solved your issue